# Create profile page using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Thanks for viewing my question. I have a program in where the user is asked to put information, basically a registration form. The inputs will be such as name, gmail, etc... This information should be displayed in an another page called profile page, in just a press of a submit button. But if an item is left blank, the word "required" should be displayed right beside of all items, and thus restarts the entire registration form. However, during the process, I noticed that there are no outputs, despite having localstorage.

Is there something wrong with it? Thanks.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <form role = "form"  onsubmit="signUp(event);">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="pswrd" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
                 
            </div>
        </form>
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <div id="results">
                
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        const signUp = e => {
             let forminfo = {
                fname: document.getElementById('name1').value,
                lname: document.getElementById('name2').value,
                email: document.getElementById('email').value,
                pwsrd: document.getElementById('pswrd').value 
            }
        localStorage.setItem('forminfo', JSON.stringify(forminfo));
        //console.log(localStorage.getItem('forminfo'));
        dispData();
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        }
                
        function dispData (){
            if(localStorage.getItem('forminfo')){
            //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('forminfo')));
            let {fname, lname, email, pswrd} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('forminfo'));
            var results = document.getElementById('results');
            results.innerHTML ='
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Name</td>
                            <td>${name1}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                            <td>${name2}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>${email}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td>${pswrd}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            ';  
        }
        dispData();     

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now i solved it for you [here](https://codepen.io/agandurmisevic/pen/poaVPqG)

```js
let button = document.getElementById("signup");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let forminfo = {
    fname: document.getElementById('name1').value,
    lname: document.getElementById('name2').value,
    email: document.getElementById('email').value,
    pswrd: document.getElementById('pswrd').value 
  };
  dispData(forminfo);
});
                    
function dispData(forminfo) {
  if(forminfo) {
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    results.innerHTML = `<table
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>First Name</td>
                                <td>${forminfo.fname}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Last Name</td>
                                <td>${forminfo.lname}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>${forminfo.email}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password</td>
                                <td>${forminfo.pswrd}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>`;  
    }
}
```

```html
        <div class = "container">
            <h1>Registration</h1>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name1" value="test" id="name1" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name2" value="test" id="name2" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" value="test@test.de" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" value="test" name="pswrd" id="pswrd" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="signup">Register</button>
                     
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Results</h2>
            <div id="results">
                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Never use `.onclick()` from a userscript!

Userscripts operate in a sandbox ("isolated world") and `onclick()` operates in the target-page scope and cannot see any functions your script creates.

Always use `addEventListener()`

Like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener ("click", () => {
    var name = document.getElementById('name1');   
    console.log(name.value);
});
```

```html
<div class = "container">
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="button">Register</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <div id="results">
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do I exactly put the first code in my javascript area? Thanks

Comment: On your form remove `onsubmit="signUp(event);"`and add to your button id="signup". Than change `const signUp = e => {` with  var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener ("click", () => {

Comment: Then the rest should be kept? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at my other answer. You can simply hand in the Local Storage result as a parameter. Then you don't always have to call the storage. See below